# Issue of PHP and MySql function

Tags: php, mysql

while fetching data from MySQL for today's  date, what should be preferred why

```
1) "select * from table1 where created_dt Like CURDATE()";
2) "select * from table1 where created_dt Like ".date(Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

will it make any difference in execution time of the script, If i use MySql function instead of php function or vice versa

Comment: IMHO, the SQL version should be used as internal DB optimization will be used.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, I would go with the first as it just works with mysql rather than mixing.

Comment: Do the one that's easiest to understand and port.  worrying about performance constraints on a code line like this one is a micro-optimization.

Comment: The latter invokes neither valid MySQL nor valid PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will it make any difference in execution time of the script

## Definitely NO.

Comment: This is not an answer, its preaching.

It may be entirely true that premature optimisation is the root of all evil, but that doesn't mean that you categorically deny that there is a difference between micro-optimised versions - by all means argue that there is no worth to it, but not that it doesn't exist (especially without qualifying the statement).

There is, however, a much more important lesson the OP needs to learn, and that is that algorithm choice (particularly regarding index usage in SQL) is important, if you intend your app to scale to any reasonable size.

Answer (score -1):

The difference would be pretty negligable, though generating the date in SQL would probably be marginally faster.

You should not be using 'like' though, since that is for partial string comparisons, and you are using a date field (which, internally, will be an integer). You are also missing two sets of quotes for your php date example.

But most importantly, if you are using a datetime format for created_dt, and then attempting to match by date using date(created_dt) or any kind of string comparison, you will not be taking advantage of indexing, and are likely to cause a full table scan.  You'd be better using:

```
select * from table1 where created_dt between CURDATE() and date_add(CURDATE(), interval 1 day);
```

Which can take advantage of a btree index on created_dt to make your query perform considerably faster and more efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to use option `1` - date value computed on the database server because:

- MySQL doesn't need to convert the string value from the query to a date, since `CURDATE` retrieves a DATE value
- the PHP `date` function parses the parameter and formates the date and concatenates the result to the query string, which is surely a more complex task then the mysql `CURDATE` function which has no parameters and simply retrieves the date